# fetching field in laravel query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two tables user_master and user_teams with common field user_name.
I want to join the table and get the team value group by teams 
tried as

```
$filter_teams = DB::table('user_teams')
->join('user_master','user_master.user_name','=','user_teams.user_name')
->whereIn('user_master.geo',$geo)
->groupBy('user_teams.team')
->pluck('user_teams.team')
->toArray();
```

by may values are duplicating.I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 0):

since you didn't determine select fields ... the default will be '*'
this is why you are getting duplicated fields ...

just add :

```
->select('user_teams.team')
```

and i think that all.

i recommend not using group without aggregation ....
so my advice your query to like this:

```
$filter_teams = DB::table('user_teams')
->join('user_master','user_master.user_name','=','user_teams.user_name')
->whereIn('user_master.geo',$geo)
->select('user_teams.team')->distinct()
->pluck('user_teams.team')
->toArray();
```